# Parsing url in python to extract parameters

Tags: python, url-rewriting, urllib

I have an URL in python like

```
localhost:8080&id=123&id=345&name=john
```

Is there a library which can parse this and get the key value pair of all the parameters? As I want to again create url as a combination of the initial parameters using say `id` feild so I would have two new URLs.

`localhost:8080&id=123&name=john` and
`localhost:8080&id=345&name=john`

I'm using this code in python 2.7 but it doesn't bring both the id's

```
parse_url = urlparse(url)
query_dict = dict(parse_qsl(parse_url.query))
print query_dict
```

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is explicitly off topic. See: [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this with a regex

```
import re
components = [re.split(":|=", component) for component in <url>.split("&")]
url_dict = {component[0]: component[1] for component in components}
```

Comment: I just gave a basic example. The URL is a lot more complex so I feel using URL decoder is much easier.